# Need Seprate Category Page for custom post types

Tags: php, wordpress

I have created a custom post types(passion) and i am using built in categories for it.

Please note that i am also using built in posts for home page which is working fine, it has its own category,archive page.

"Passion" post type is for paid user. My custom posts are working fine. But i am unable to create a category page for "passion" post type so that if user goes to url
"www.site.com/passion/dance" it shows all the "passion" custom posts with "dance" category. I am using WCK plugin to create post types.
I have tried creating archive-passion.php,category-passion.php, taxonomy-passion.php files but nothing worked.

Answer (score 0):

Use `http://domain.com/category/dance/?post_type=passion` for CPT and add custom code in your `archive-passion.php`